# htaccess maintenance mode with relative url

Tags: .htaccess

I am using the following in my `.htaccess` to place my site in maintenance mode:

```
##################################################
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11\.111\.111\.111
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/maintenance.html [R=307,L]
##################################################
```

My question is how do I make this relative rather than absolute, so I don't need the `http://domain.com` part?

Thanks!

Comment: Relative as in the `maintenance.html` file will always be in the folder the htaccess file is in? Or just being able to put the htaccess file in any folder?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jon. The `.htaccess` file will be in the root. I would like to specify the location of the `maintenance.html` relative to the root without having to include the domain. So I have a single .htaccess file I can drop into any project without having to change it

Comment: But yes the `maintenance.html` can be in the same root folder as the `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to specify the location of the maintenance.html relative
>   to the root without having to include the domain. So I have a single
>   .htaccess file I can drop into any project without having to change it

Perhaps, just use the `HTTP_HOST` variable so you don't have a hardcoded domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11\.111\.111\.111
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/maintenance.html [R=307,L]
```